# Where can I find global_tracker.xml?

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

I was going through Google Analytics docs for Android ([here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#overview)). It refers to R.xml.global_tracker. Where can I find the source for global_tracker.xml to see how its configured?